# Keep terminal open at the end of bash script

Tags: windows, bash

I'm trying to run a `bash` script from `cmd`. When I execute the script a new terminal is opened an immediately closed since there is some problem with it. Because its happening so fast I can't read the problem. I'm looking for a way to keep the terminal open once the script exits.

Comment: send stderr to a file when executing eg. `bash something 2> errors`

Comment: Add a sleep at the end so you can read an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go horribly Windows-y with this:

```
read -p "Press any key to continue" x
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also put a `$SHELL` in a new line at the end of your script. The window will stay open, no matter from where you open your shell script (e.g. cmd / powershell / etc).

Answer (score 0):

to test a .sh script in windows cmd (assuming you have bash installed and in your path                   environment variable):
     cd into parent directory,
     type "bash" to enter bash console,
     type "./",
     type "exit" to exit bash console

Answer (score 0):

Add bash at the end of the script

It works for me.